# The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller?

Tags: actionscript-3, indexing, stack

I having problems setting the child index of a sprite... It works perfectly on the first run of the program, but fails on the second time around. For context this function is in a class which accepts an array of sprites and displays them. My problem is with `setChildIndex(_selected as DisplayObject, numChildren-1);`

```
private function enlarge(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (!_open)
        {
            _selected = e.currentTarget;
            _selectedOrigX = _selected.x;
            _selectedOrigY = _selected.y;
            _selectedID = _selected.id;

            _open = true;

            setChildIndex(_selected as DisplayObject, numChildren-1);

            new TweenLite(_selected, 0.5, {width:984, height:640, x:0, y:0, ease:Bounce.easeOut} );

            _yes = new Yes_btn();
            addChild(_yes);

            _no = new No_btn();
            addChild(_no);

            _yes.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selected);
            _no.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cancel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you setting the "_selected" object's mouseChildren property?

Comment: ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller

Comment: The problem was that I was forgetting to remove the old event listeners before adding the new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was where I had forgot to remove the previous Event Listeners from the objects. With the following code everything works correctly again.

`addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removed);`

```
private function removed(e:Event):void
    {
        for (var i:uint; i < _objectsArray.length; i ++)
        {
            var object:Sprite = _objectsArray[i];

            object.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, enlarge);

        }
    }
```